# is there way to lint a specific variable name with eslint

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lint, eslint

For example, I want to eliminate a specific variable name like $abc or '$abc', if it exist anywhere, we will throw a linting error. Its specifically for es6 code or just javascript code.

How can I do that in eslint? is it possble?

If its not what is the alternative I can do to check that without pollute my code base?

Comment: [What have you tired?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Have you looked at the docs for ["Working with Rules"](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules)?

Comment: I'd like to introduce you to my friend [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/egrep)...

Comment: @gfullam I tried to google this specific topic over all on the internet, so far I have been using the default configable rules, but I have not found one that somehow match a custom variable name

Comment: It looks like what you are looking for is not a default rule (https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2431) instead you would need to write a custom rule (http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules).

Answer (score 6):

You can create [your own eslint rule](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules) as mentioned in the comments. Here is a small example that reports all identifiers (excluding property names) with name `foo`:

```
export default function(context) {
  return {
    Identifier(node) {
      if (
        node.name === 'foo' && 
        (
          node.parent.type !== 'MemberExpression' ||
          node.parent.computed ||
          node.parent.object === node
        )
      ) {
        context.report(node, 'Do not use the variable name "foo"');
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Live example: http://astexplorer.net/#/Lmzgbm2iRq

Answer (score -1):

You could traverse the codebase and check all the files for the presence of the variable you wish to eliminate. It's perhaps a bit heavyweight for what you need but it might be an option.

Something like this should do the trick. You will have to replace $bad_variable_name with whatever your actual
 variable is. You will also have to do something to make your build fail (if desired)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var checkDir = (dir) => {   
  var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  files.forEach((file) => {
    var path = dir + '/' + file;
    var stat = fs.statSync(path);
    if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
      checkDir(path);
    } else {
      if(path.endsWith('this-file.js')){ //the file where this code is
        return;
      }
      var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(path);
      if(fileContents.indexOf('$bad_variable_name') > -1){ 
        console.log('$bad_variable_name found in ' + path);                 
        //do something here to fail your build
      }
    }
  });
};
```